# oc debug on a stateful set results in PVC errors

Tags: debugging, openshift, kubernetes-statefulset, kubernetes-pvc

I'm running a stateful set in Openshift 4.3 which does not start properly. I suspect permissions issues, but that's not directly relevant to the question. I'm having problems getting a debug container to start.

I run the command to create the stateful set and other relevant objects. The pod created for the stateful set (I'm only running one replica at the moment) crashes (which I expect). Then I issue the command `oc debug statefulset/[ss-name]` and I get an error saying that the primary container is invalid because `* spec.containers[0].volumeMounts[0].name: Not found: "volume"`

The volume *does* exist, though - it's called 'volume' and it creates successfully when I start up the stateful set.

I'm sure I'm just missing something when it comes to the creation of the debug pod, but I'm not sure what - I can't find anything on Google that suggests that I would need to create a separate PVC for the debug pod or anything. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured out the issue, here. When you start up a debug pod, it's a deployment of its own, and is NOT part of the stateful set. That's why it couldn't find the volume - the volume was created as part of the stateful set, and creating a debug pod creates nothing except the pod, with none of the other SS trappings.

I was able to start the debug pod by removing the section where it attempted to mount the volume, instead having that folder use the ephemeral storage that's local to the pod (since I didn't care what happened to the data on it anyway).